# How to move object internals out?

Tags: c++11, move, move-semantics

Let us consider the following class:

```
class Big
{
public: 
    std::vector<int> convertToVector();
private:
    std::vector<int> data_;
};
```

I want `Big::convertToVector()` to gut the object and **move** the data outside.

I was considering:

```
std::vector<int> Big::convertToVector()
{
    return std::move(data_);
}
```

Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: Yes.That is the way to move the data_ out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the correct way.

You have to be very careful, though, because your old vector is left in an unspecified state; you might want to empty it to avoid surprises.

```
std::vector<int> Big::convertToVector() {
    std::vector<int> temp;
    std::swap(temp, _data);

    return std::move(temp);
}
```

Comment: Any object that has been moved has to remain valid, so the swap is not needed. I was just not sure about the return type.

Comment: @MartinDrozdik oopsie, appears you're right - *guaranteed to leave the moved-from argument in valid but unspecified state*. Which incidentally still makes my solution reasonable, I'd say. It should also incur minimal runtime overhead.

Comment: @MartinDrozdik And while we're at it, if you wrote it as `std::vector<int> Big::convertToVector() &&`, you could skip that swap entirely, because the object should be destroyed after the call anyway.

Comment: [Here's an example of that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/389fc07f55180452)

Answer (score -1):

as long as I know, std::vector has move constructor, so you just do (as I always do with other containers)

```
std::vector<int> Big::convert_to_vector() { return data_; }
```

Comment: This just creates a copy of the `data_`